# Vectorized String Replacement showing weird behaviour

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a few dataframes that match pattern and replacement strings for replacement purposes. The first few lines of one look like this:

```
> df
  pattern repl
1       1  111
2       2  112
3       3  113
4       5  114
5       6  115
```

I want to replace strings in a given vector (which we will call `str_vector` here). Suppose, `str_vector` looks like this:

```
> str_vector
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  NA  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
```

I am not able to replace the elements in `str_vector` that match `df$pattern` with the corresponding `df$repl` string. I read a lot of threads on this issue, however, nothing did work so far. Using `qdap`, `stringr` and `stringi` returns:

```
> qdap::mgsub(df$pattern,df$repl,str_vector)
 [1] "111"           "1111112"       "1111113"       "4"             NA             
 [6] "1111111111114" "7"             "8"             "9"             "1110"

> stringr::str_replace(df$pattern,df$repl,str_vector)
 [1] "1" "2" "3" "5" "6" "1" "2" "3" "5" "6"

> stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(df$pattern,df$repl,str_vector,vectorize_all = TRUE)
 [1] "1" "2" "3" "5" "6" "1" "2" "3" "5" "6"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards and thank you very much!

---

Reproduction of `df` and `str_vector`:

```
df<-structure(list(pattern = c("1", "2", "3", "5", "6"), repl = c("111", 
"112", "113", "114", "115")), .Names = c("pattern", "repl"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

str_vector<-c("1", "2", "3", "4", NA, "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `str_vector` should become `111 112 113 NA NA 115`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option

```
v1 <- unname(setNames(df$repl, df$pattern)[str_vector])
i1 <- which(!is.na(v1))
v1[i1[1]:i1[length(i1)]]
#[1] "111" "112" "113" NA    NA    "115"
```